# jasmine + protractor byID failing

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Here's my HTML, which is present and valid.  When I break on the testcases using WebStorm, I can inspect the page and see this element just fine...

```
<a id="privacyPolicy1234" on-tap="goPrivacyPolicy()" class="disable-user-behavior">Privacy Policy</a>
```

Here is my Jasmine test, which is failing to find the element.

```
it("should list a privacyPolicy ", function() {

    privacyPolicyElement = element(by.id('privacyPolicy1234'));
    expect(privacyPolicyElement.getText()).toContain("Privacy Policy");
```

The error coming back

```
 Message:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("privacyPolicy1234")
```

edit:

Also tried to put it in one line, and getting `false` where I expect `true`

```
expect(element(by.id('privacyPolicy1234')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `browser.sleep()` which makes the test non-reliable and slower, use an *explicit wait*. For instance, you can wait for the "privacy policy" element to become present:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    privacyPolicyElement = element(by.id('privacyPolicy1234'));

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(privacyPolicyElement), 5000);

expect(privacyPolicyElement.getText()).toContain("Privacy Policy");
```

It's important to note that in this case protractor would wait *up to* 5 seconds, checking the presence of the element every 500 ms (by default). Once the condition is met, it stops waiting. If after 5 seconds, the element would still not become present - you'll get a timeout exception.

Comment: Thank you!  Generally if the element never becomes present, and I get the timeout Exception, does the test fail?

Comment: @Erik yes, it would fail with a timeout exception. You can also provide a custom error message as a third argument (after the timeout value, 5000 in the example above).

Comment: @Erik I doubt that. Could you please add more details about the `doesn't seem to properly wait`? Thanks!

Comment: alexce, I erased my question.  Turns out the css element is not present when I am rendering the page in differing resolutions.. this was a bug in the page, not the test.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I'm testing the page before it loads..

as a work around I added

```
it("should list a privacyPolicy ", function() {
    browser.sleep(2000);
    privacyPolicyElement = element(by.id('privacyPolicy1234'));
```